# Why can't I add a generic stripchart function to my package?

Tags: r

I'm using roxygen2 to create the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files in my package.

The problem I am having seems to come about from the generic stripchart function I created. I thought stripchart was part of R's base graphics. My stripchart generic uses the tidyr and lattice libraries.

When I "Check" my package after building, I get the following errors:

```
Error : object 'stripchart' not found whilst loading namespace 'mypackage'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mypackage’
Execution halted

checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... WARNING
Error: object 'stripchart' not found whilst loading namespace 'mypackage'
Execution halted

A namespace must be able to be loaded with just the base namespace
loaded: otherwise if the namespace gets loaded by a saved object, the
session will be unable to start.

Probably some imports need to be declared in the NAMESPACE file.
```

This is are namespace imports which is missing stripchart, but every time but I can't add this in manually because roxygen2 will overwrite it:

```
importFrom(graphics,barplot)
importFrom(graphics,legend)
importFrom(graphics,par)
importFrom(graphics,text)
importFrom(utils,download.file)
importFrom(utils,read.table)
```

Below are the Imports and Depends in my Description file:

```
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.0)
Imports:
    bio3d (>= 2.2-2),
    XML (>= 3.98-1.4),
    RCurl (>= 1.95-4.8),
    httr (>= 1.1.0),
    lattice (>= 0.20-33),
    tidyr (>= 0.5.1)
```

Is the problem that i'm missing `importFrom(graphics,stripchart)`? If so, how do I add this without roxygen2 overwriting it?